# Put an asp label under another without space between them

Tags: asp.net, webforms, label

In a column I have a div container which contains two asp labels, one under the other.

```
        <td>
            <div>
                <h2><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmployeeFullname" Text="Claudie"></asp:Label></h2>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIdEmployee" Text="34343d-dfadfsf-3433"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </td>
```

There is a blank space between the labels and I am trying to remove it.
Below a screenshot in design mode.

[image]

I want them to be together without any space in between.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens by the fact that the 'h2' tag has its own browser-specific margin top/bottom style.

You can disable it something like this:

```
<h2 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;">...</h2>

<h2 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmployeeFullname" Text="Claudie"></asp:Label></h2>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIdEmployee" Text="34343d-dfadfsf-3433"></asp:Label>
```